# Generating a CSS grid layout using DIV issue

Tags: css, html

I was hoping someone could point out what I am doing wrong with my CSS/HTML.

I’m rolling my own personal Google/ig replacement, so you know what I am going for.

The boxes shouldn’t have that giant space in between the rows. I was hopping all the boxes would just line up with each other like the do on the last column on the right.

Forgive me, CSS isn't my forte. If I am going about this all wrong, please by all means, school me. I am here to learn.

Any help?

**This is what I get**
[image: What I get]

**And with the magic of photoshop, this is what I want to happen.**

[image]

**Running the Web Developer Div Size Tool, I get this:**
[image]

**Relevant HTML**

Each `widget-container` is repeated for each site. Then the `li` is looped to generate the `ul`

```
<div id="content">

<--! Begin repeated content →
    <div id="widget-container">

    <div id="widget-head">
      <h3><a href="#" target="_blank">FEED TITLE</a></h3>
      <div id="widget-edit">EditButton</div>
    </div>

    <div id="widget-content">
      <ul id="widget-feeds">

        <li>
        <a href="#" onclick=""> <img src="images/icons/hidden.gif"> </a> 
        <a href="#" target="_blank" title="" >Feed Link</a>
        <div class="widget-desc"> Content Here </div>
        </li> 

        <li>
        <a href="#" onclick=""> <img src="images/icons/hidden.gif"> </a> 
        <a href="#" target="_blank" title="" >Feed Link</a>
        <div class="widget-desc"> Content Here </div>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="#" onclick=""> <img src="images/icons/hidden.gif"> </a> 
        <a href="#" target="_blank" title="" >Feed Link</a>
        <div class="widget-desc"> Content Here </div>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="fclear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And the relevant CSS document**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Reset */
body,img,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,ul,ol {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; border:none;}
/* End Reset */

body {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-family: Arial,Verdana,Sans-Serif;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
a {
    color: #36C;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.fclear {clear:both}

#content #widget-container {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-head {
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 25px;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-head h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-head #widget-edit {
    float: right;
    width: 12px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 1px;

}
#content #widget-container #widget-content #widget-feeds {

}
#content #widget-container #widget-content #widget-feeds ul {
overflow: auto;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-content #widget-feeds li {
    display: block;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important; 
    padding: 4px 0 9px 0 !important;
}
#content #widget-container #widget-content #widget-feeds li a {


}
#content #widget-container #widget-content #widget-feeds li .widget-desc {
    white-space: normal;
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You can inspect Element and see what is causing that spacing -- this can either be caused by margin, padding, or simply the size of the container.

Comment: I have inspected the elements, but there is not erroneous sizes being generated.

Comment: I edited my question to show the size containers.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the way elements wrap around spaces:

See the thing is that the highest element defines the line height which create the inconsistencies.

What I've would have done would be to set a standard height, thus everything will be perfectly aligned.

If you're keen on filling in the gaps, you might want to look at the following JS plugin:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Hmmm So you think one element is throwing the others off?

Comment: Yup, you can test it by setting a height to your fragment containers